# ELSE IF in algorithmic package

Tags: algorithmicx, algorithmic

Is there a command in `algorithmic` package which is similar to `\ElsIf` in `algorithmicx`? ( I do not want each nested **if**  to be indented).

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Yes there is: `\ELSIF`. This is one of the *first* examples taken from the [`algorithms` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.pdf) (section **3.2 The *if-then-else* Statement**, p 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
  \IF{some condition is true}
    \STATE do some processing
  \ELSIF{some other condition is true}
    \STATE do some different processing
  \ELSIF{some even more bizarre condition is met}
    \STATE do something else
  \ELSE
    \STATE do the default actions
  \ENDIF
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

If you are using [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) you have to use `\ElsIf`. Here is a mirror of the above pseudocode using `algpseudocode`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
  \If{some condition is true}
    \State do some processing
  \ElsIf{some other condition is true}
    \State do some different processing
  \ElsIf{some even more bizarre condition is met}
    \State do something else
  \Else
    \State do the default actions
  \EndIf
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could I also use `ElsIf` ?

Comment: @alper: The [`algorithms` bundle](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) (which provides the `algorithmic` package) only supplies capitalized keywords (like `\ELSIF`). The [`algorithmicx` bundle](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) (which provides the `algpseudocode` and other packages) provides `\ElsIf` and the like; `algcompatible` would provide `\ELSIF`.

Comment: If I use `\usepackage{algorithmic}` instead of `\usepackage{algorithmicx}` could it be also done?

Comment: @alper: Sure; in fact, that's what I show in my example.

Comment: Ah sorry I meant using `algorithmicx` instead of `algorithmic` ; but `\ElsIf` does do job when I use `algorithmicx`